# Position on foreach

Tags: php, html

How to start the position into 1 instead of 0?

Because the first name starts in 0. All I need to do is to make the first name to start in 1 and end in 50.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

here are my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SEATPLAN</title>
</head>

    <body>
        <table border = "2" cellpadding = "20" cellspacing = "10">                 
            <tr>
                <td colspan = 5 rowspan = 2> </td>
                <td align = "center"> Teachers Table</td>
                <td colspan = 5 rowspan = 2> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = 1 rowspan = 6 width="1000"> </td>
            </tr>

        <?php
                $names = array('Acog','Alaya-ay','Anino','Balsa','Baron','Borda','Bravo','Dalagan','Detumal','Enriquez',    
                                'Hernane','Jose','Laminero','Montilla','Moraclo','Ogang','Palencia','Palencia','Pandili',
                                'Ramo','Ravelo','Septio','Tapel','Tayone','Trinidad','Yntong','Student','Student','Student',
                                'Student','Student','Student','Student','Student','Student','Student','Student','Student',
                                'Student','Student','Student','Student','Student','Student','Student','Student','Student'
                                ,'Student','Student','Student');
            ?>

        <?php
                foreach($names as $position => $name){
                     echo "<td width='500' align='center'>".$position."<br>".$name."<br/>";
                        if ($position == 9){
                            echo "<tr width='500' align='center'>"."<br/>";}
                        if ($position == 19){
                            echo "<tr width='500' align='center'>"."<br/>";}
                        if ($position == 29){
                            echo "<tr width='500' align='center'>"."<br/>";}
                        if ($position == 39){
                            echo "<tr width='500' align='center'>"."<br/>";}
                        }
            ?>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($names as $name) {
     echo '<td>'. $i .': '. $name .'</td>';
     if($i % 10 == 0)
         echo '</tr><tr>';
     $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest solution if you later want to use the key (`$position`) for anything else:

```
echo "<td width='500' align='center'>".($position+1)."<br>".$name."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new variable and initialize it with `$position + 1`.

```
foreach($names as $position => $name){
    $newPosition = $position + 1;
    echo "<td width='500' align='center'>".$newPosition."<br>".$name."<br/>";
    .
    .
}
```

This will preserve the value of current `$position` also.

Answer (score 0):

All numeric arrays start with 0 as it's first index.

Just do this trick, it won't change the array structure but will show what you want:

```
foreach($names as $position => $name){
    echo "<td width='500' align='center'>".($position+1)."<br>".$name."<br/>";
    // rest of the code
}
```

So it will always add 1 to the actual position.